# Нахождение бота на веб странице определёное время

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование

Мне нужно создать бота на python, желательно 3 версии, который будет открывать веб страницу, ждать несколько секунд и закрывать её.
Единственное что я смог сделать:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Но это не совсем то, открывается окно браузера, а хотелось бы в фоновом режиме.

Может кто знает как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')

Comment: self.driver.stop_client()
self.driver.quit()

Comment: Возможно, это то что надо, но я не совсем понял, происходит то же самое. Браузер открылся а после закрылся

Comment: chrome_options.add_argument('headless')  У меня с этой опцией он не открывается вы её надеюсь до вызова chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com") используете?

Comment: Конечно, в самом начале скрипта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ChromeDriver:
    def __init__(self):
         chrome_driver = 'C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe'
         chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
         chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
         chrome_options.add_argument('headless')

         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)
         self.driver.get('http://top-radio.ru/web/rap-live-russkij-rep')

         self.play_id = self.driver.find_element_by_id("svg_play_2")
         self.pause_id = self.driver.find_element_by_id("svg_pause_1")

    def play(self):
         self.play_id.click()
    def pause(self):
        self.pause_id.click()

    def driver_quit(self):
         self.driver.stop_client()
         self.driver.quit()
radio =  ChromeDriver()
radio.play()
```

Comment: Запустите этот код если он откроет браузер тогда я не знаю кстати какая OS у вас?

Comment: Этот скрипт должен начать проигрывать русский RAP

Comment: У меня Linux, добавил строки chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
         chrome_options.add_argument('headless') и заработало, открывается в фоне, спасибо!